# Autodesk Forge Viewer: Selection-event not working anymore after adding a custom model

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

I am working on the example from [Custom models in Forge Viewer](https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/custom-models-forge-viewer) blog entry from Petr Broz.

The problem I am facing at the moment is, that the `Autodesk.Viewing.SELECTION_CHANGED_EVENT` event is not raised any more after calling the `sceneBuilder.addNewModel` method.
To test the issue i've modified the [Codepen-example](https://codepen.io/petrbroz/pen/gOaaoxz):

Add a new function:

```
function onSelection(event) {
    event.dbIdArray.forEach(selection => {
        console.log(`selected ${selection}`)
    });
}
```

...and register the function as event listener (as first step in the setup):

```
[...]
forgist.setup(document.getElementById('viewer'), 2).then(viewer => {
    viewer.addEventListener(Autodesk.Viewing.SELECTION_CHANGED_EVENT, onSelection)
    [...]
```

As long as I don't click the "Add geometry" button, the selection is shown in the console, but afterwards nothing is printed.

edit: the `viewer.getSelection()` method still returns the correct id of the selected objects

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case of creating a multi model environment, you would have to use 
[AGGREGATE_SELECTION_CHANGED_EVENT](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/viewer/v2/reference/javascript/guiviewer3d/#aggregate-selection-changed-event) to be notified about selections

Comment: can we able to call this event in button click?

Comment: You don't call this event, but you can trigger it by changing the selection using the viewer.select() method - you can do that from a button click handler as well  if you want